How to Switching File paths for images or textures
I would like some help figuring this thing out, Basically i have a model which has textures, the textures have the same name but the file path is different (its in a different folder), what i want is a way to select the model or textures and switch its textures from one file path to another (Multiple textures at once). thanks!
BTW there is a tool in Maya called "File Path Editor" which does what i want you select what you need in terms of paths and you can re-path (change the path) the texture.

i think he wants to remap multiple images/textures and basically say "this is my new textures folder" - not just replace one image as the solution in your proposal

hi thanks for your comments @GordonBrinkmann , no idk timdan, but im guessing he is looking for the same thing, Chris summed it up nicely, i want to remap where the textures are.
for example i have a character that has the same Geo and Uvs, but i want to switch the textures like skins(different colors), so i want to make these texture remap/repath to a different folder instead of doing it one by one in the image viewer.

A hacky way of doing this would be to rename your current textures folder to ..._bak for example, then open your file in blender and go to File > External Data > Find Missing Files. Then you can select the new textures image folder.

hi, i guess you can but it wont be the best option when collaborating with different people on a project

In that case I would recommend creating a script or even an addon that caters to the needs of your group.
A simple script to swap a folder name from all image texture paths would look like this:
import bpy
import os

old_folder_name = "old_folder_name"
new_folder_name = "new_folder_name"

# Function to replace folder name in texture path
def replace_folder_name_in_texture_paths(old_folder_name, new_folder_name):
    for tex in bpy.data.images:
        if tex.filepath:
            tex.filepath = tex.filepath.replace(old_folder_name, new_folder_name)
            
replace_folder_name_in_texture_paths(old_folder_name, new_folder_name)

